# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Referring [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2564316/668308) answer, I tried to evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ by using contour integral $\int_C\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z}dz$ where $C$ is a upper half circle of radius $R$ centered at $0$. By Cauchy theorem,
$$0=\int_C\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z}dz = \int_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ix}-1}{x}dx-\pi i+\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}\operatorname{exp}(iR\cos\theta)d\theta$$
and the second summand $\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$. From this, I think we conclude
$$\pi i = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x}dx$$
but how can I conclude $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Hint: What is the relation between $\sin x$ and $e^{ix}$?

Comment: @Kolja Ok the imaginary part is the key. But $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi$ implies $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is an obvious fact? just because the integrand is even function?

Comment: That is correct !

Comment: @OliverDiaz No. This is a different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the imaginary part on both sides:
$$\Im(\pi i) = \Im \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\implies\pi=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Now use the symmetry of the integrand to change bounds.